Coin flip 5 heads in a row how much would you pay interview question
I was trying out interview questions in preparation for quant interview season and came across this question: Flip a coin 5 times in a row. If you get 5 Heads, you get 28 dollars. How much would you pay to play? How about if you get to play this 5000 times?
My simple answer to this would be I would pay \$0.875, and if I play it 5000 times, I would pay \$4375. However, my answer seems a little off in the sense that the game is highly skewed. Meaning, most of the time I am actually going to lose my \$0.875 for each play, but only when I play the game many times, would I get close to the expected value.
Meaning, my value for 5000 games of \$4375 seems to be closer to the right answer but perhaps the single-play answer needs to be adjusted even further down because the risk-reward is so low? Does anyone have any idea if this thought process is correct and if so, how should the adjustment be made?
Thank you :)

I think you could also find the variance of the payoff of a single game, and argue that since 5000 is a large number, the average payoff will be approximately Gaussian with the appropriate mean and variance. Then you could set a level of risk-averseness $k$, and say you will pay 5000 $\times$ (the payoff of $\mu - k\sigma$).
I think this is exploiting the property of CLT that no matter how skewed your initial distribution is, when it is repeated independently for a large number of iterations, the average will be pretty symmetric

I see I see. However, in the case of a single bet should you not just avoid it? If we liken this to a roulette wheel with 8 sections: you win $10 in one section, and the others return no money, but it costs you $1 to spin this wheel and play the game. Do you play it if you only had $1? Even though EV is positive, if the risk of ruin is asymmetrically high relative to your available money, should you not avoid these bets?

This is a valid question. I think these questions asked by quant firms test how well you could translate your intuition into mathematical rules that can be written down and converted to computer algorithms (i.e. trading ideas -> strategies). For the roulette scenario, one could use a utility function instead: if the state of being with 0 dollars is unbearable, choose a utility function such that $U(0) = -\infty$, so that the mean will also be negative infinity, and you can apply the previous rule to it.
